# javascript conditional import doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm building a Vue.js application with the webpack template.

Since I have some test that works with mocked api I would need to import those api only when I'm testing.
In order to do that I have added a conditional import in my `main.js` file:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing') {
    import('apiMocking')
    .then(() => {
       console.log('mocked api imported');
    });
}
```

This way, when I run the test, they are using my mocked apis, when I run the application I'm using the actual apis. The problem is that with this configuration I have the following error in Firefox, as soon as the application starts:

> SyntaxError: ... 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top
>   level

And then just a blank page.
In Chrome everything works fine...how can I solve this?

EDIT: I am already using wepback + babel, my webpack configuration is taken from this vue template: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack
then I also added Babel:

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 8"]
      }
    }],
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-vue-jsx", "transform-runtime"]
}
```

Then in my `webpack.base.conf` file:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test'), resolve('node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client')]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

[`import()`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) is only currently at Stage 3 in the [JavaScript proposals process](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/) (unlike `import` and `export`, which were in ES2015). You cannot rely on Stage 3 proposal support in the wild. Apparently, recent Chrome supports it, and recent Firefox does not, yet.

If you want to use proposals before they reach Stage 4 (at least), you typically have to use a transpiler like Babel and/or a bundler like Webpack or Browserify.

Comment: Updated answer!

Comment: @ste - You mean "question." Are you sure that configuration handles dynamic import?